# Django limit access by group only

Tags: django, django-admin

I only you can limit what a user can do via the user permissions in admin.. But is there a way to limit them in admin via what group you add them to?

I want to allow a certain group to do everything in that model if they belong to a certain group

thanks!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If you look at the `Group` model in the admin you can set permissions there.  You can add people to a group by looking at their `User` model.